# How can I concatenate numpy arrays from two pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two Dataframes storing numpy arrays. I would like to concatenate all numpy arrays from Dataframe 1 with those from Dataframe 2. How can I archieve this ?

A possible solution could look like this:

```
def concat_df(df, other_df):
    for column in df.columns.values:
        for (_, row1), (_, row2) in zip(df.iterrows(), other_df.iterrows()):
            row1[column] = np.concatenate(row1[column], row2[column])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
out=pd.Series(np.concatenate([df['column name'].values, other_df['column name'].values]))
```

**OR**

```
out=df['column name'].append(other_df['column name'],ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

```
out=pd.Series(np.hstack([df['column name'].values,other_df['column name'].values]))
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your required Series

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same columns you can use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

`new_df = pd.concat([df, other_df])`

Comment: Otherwise, if the length is same we can rename the columns 1st `other_df.columns = df.columns`